# SSIS Excel mix match data type import issue

Tags: excel, ssis

I am using an excel source task to import data from excel to my database.  My excel doc is saved in xls.  One of the columns is a mix between strings and ints.  I have tried multiple solutions that I found online.  One, I have changed the data type in excel for that column to text, I have flipped the data so that the strings are at the top.

When I did those items, it gave nulls for either strings or the ints, depending on how the data was sorted.  The top 8 rows were identified as strings, it pulled nulls for the ints.  If the top eight rows were ints, the strings became null.

Also, I found this solution: to add IMEX to the end of the connection string in the properties "EXCEL 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1".  When I did this plus all the other items attempted, it actually excluded my strings from my data set and didn't bring those rows into the import.

Any other solutions to try?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find my solution by changing it to save the excel doc as a CSV file and using a flat source file instead of an Excel source.